# US transit visa upload photo

Tags: transit-visas, us-visa

I' trying to upload my photo for the ds-160 transit visa but whenever I hit the upload photo button it gives me an error 403 or sometimes an connection error reset. Sometimes it let's me upload a photo(about once or 2x) but when I submit it, it gives me another error connection reset.

Any tips on what I should do about this?

Comment: maybe but I'm not sure. the problem with mine is that it doesn't really let me upload any photos because the error occurs before I even try to upload the photo. There were only 2x where I was able to upload the photo and the same thing happened to what that link is describing.

Comment: I recommend clean/delete all the cookies from your computer (restart it) and try again... It looks like more a problem from computer rather than the page.